# Send bit to Siemens Logo 8 with Python (modbus connection)

Tags: python, modbus, siemens

I am trying to send 1 bit from my pc (192.168.0.2) to Siemens network input (IP: 192.168.0.11:504) with Python. But i can't get it work. The goal is to send bit via modbus connection to trigger BO31 condition.

[image]

My Python code:

```
import socket
from umodbus import conf
from umodbus.client import tcp
 
# Enable values to be signed (default is False).
conf.SIGNED_VALUES = True
 
### Creating connection
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.168.0.11', 504))
 
message = tcp.write_multiple_coils(slave_id=1, starting_address=1, values=[1, 0, 0, 0])
 
# Response depends on Modbus function code. This particular returns the
# amount of coils written, in this case it is.
response = tcp.send_message(message, sock)
print(response)
sock.close()
print("Transfer finished")
```

Comment: You mentioned the IP address is 192.168.0.2 but in the code the connection is 192.168.0.11 is that correct?

Comment: sorry i corrected my question. 192.168.0.2 is my machine address and 192.168.0.11 is siemens adress

Comment: "But i can't get it work" - Please provide some details of what is not working. Does your code return an error (if so what) or does the code appear to work but not trigger BO31. If  `write_multiple_coils` is failing it may be worth trying `write_single_coil` (given your stated aim is send a single bit (the code in your question writes 4 coils).

Comment: i tried write_single_coil, and it's work now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment `tcp.write_multiple_coils(slave_id=1, starting_address=1, values=[1, 0, 0, 0])` writes four coils (1/true to coil 1 then 0/false to coils 2,3 & 4); to write a single coil either use `write_single_coil` or `tcp.write_multiple_coils(slave_id=1, starting_address=1, values=[1])` (which is best depends upon your device; not all devices implement both functions but I'd suggest starting with `write_single_coil`).